# Count longest uninterrupted NaNs through columns in pivoted Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image: img]

I have a pivoted dataframe as shown above. I am wanting to count the longest uninterrupted NaNs through the columns - not all of the NaNs. For example, for username abcd, the first week is week 2, and they have also have an entry in week 10, but they have not traded in the latest week. Therefore, the longest count of NaNs is 33

However, I also want to take into consideration the first week of trading. For username abcde, they started in week 23 and have not since traded. This means that if I were to count the largest number of NaNs, it would come back as 23 (week 1 to week 23), as opposed to week 23 to week 43

```py
dftest = df.groupby(by=["Username", "Week"], as_index=False).sum()
dftest['First Week'] = dftest.groupby('Username')['Week'].transform('min')
df_pivot = dftest.pivot(index=['Username','First Week'], columns='Week')
```

This code gives me the pivot as shown below

```
                                                Volume                     \
Week                                                  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0    
Username                  First Week                               
ab            7.0                            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
abc           20.0                           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
abcd              2.0                            NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN   
abcde                 23.0                           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
abcdef                6.0                            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   

                                                                               \
Week                                         5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0   
Username                  First Week                                 
ab            7.0                            NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN   
abc           20.0                           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
abcd              2.0                            NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN   
abcde                 23.0                           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
abcdef                6.0                            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    

                                                 ...                           \
Week                                        ... 34.0 35.0 36.0 37.0 38.0   
Username                  First Week  ...                            
ab            7.0                            NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN   
abc           20.0                           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
abcd              2.0                            NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN   
abcde                 23.0                           NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN   
abcdef                6.0                            NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0    

                                                                          
Week                                       39.0 40.0 41.0 42.0 43.0  
Username                  First Week                           
ab            7.0                            1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN   
abc           20.0                           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
abcd              2.0                            NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN   
abcde                 23.0                           NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN   
abcdef                6.0                            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I've put made a list of the columns

```py
col_list = list(df_pivot)
```

This is the list of all the columns, as shown below:

```py
[('Volume', 1.0), ('Volume', 2.0), ('Volume', 3.0), ('Volume', 4.0), ('Volume', 5.0), ('Volume', 6.0), ('Volume', 7.0), ('Volume', 8.0), ('Volume', 9.0), ('Volume', 10.0), ('Volume', 11.0), ('Volume', 12.0), ('Volume', 13.0), ('Volume', 14.0), ('Volume', 15.0), ('Volume', 16.0), ('Volume', 17.0), ('Volume', 18.0), ('Volume', 19.0), ('Volume', 20.0), ('Volume', 21.0), ('Volume', 22.0), ('Volume', 23.0), ('Volume', 24.0), ('Volume', 25.0), ('Volume', 26.0), ('Volume', 27.0), ('Volume', 28.0), ('Volume', 29.0), ('Volume', 30.0), ('Volume', 31.0), ('Volume', 32.0), ('Volume', 33.0), ('Volume', 34.0), ('Volume', 35.0), ('Volume', 36.0), ('Volume', 37.0), ('Volume', 38.0), ('Volume', 39.0), ('Volume', 40.0), ('Volume', 41.0), ('Volume', 42.0), ('Volume', 43.0)]
```

I'm just really unsure of how to get to my final solution. I'm sure that I'd need to use `.apply` on `col_list`, as there is nothing like `cumsum` / `min` / `max` that would give me my solution. I'm also not sure how I'd define a function that would take into consideration the column `'first week'`

Comment: Please provide your data as text, not images. Ideally a minimal dataset and the matching output.

Comment: @mozway I've attached what I'm able to - I can only provide limited data. Apologies about this + being new to stackoverflow.